# Regarding C# and Access DB retrieving/navigating records

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

i have established a connection to my Access database through C# although not through the normal source binding way, but through a class... see below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
static class staticConnectionString
{
    public static string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CustOrders.accdb";
}
}
```

I already have the records navigating through when the 'next' button is pressed, however i can't seem to get the 'previous' button right, any help is greatly appreciated, here's what i've used for the 'next' button.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            txtID.Text = dr["OrderNumber"].ToString();
            //int customerID = Convert.ToInt16(dr["CustomerID"].ToString());

            txtBread.Text = dr["BreadType"].ToString();
            txtFilling.Text = dr["Filling"].ToString();
            txtTop1.Text = dr["Topping1"].ToString();
            txtTop2.Text = dr["Topping2"].ToString();
            txtTop3.Text = dr["Topping3"].ToString();
            txtTop4.Text = dr["Topping4"].ToString();
            txtSauce.Text = dr["SauceType"].ToString();
            txtToasted.Text = dr["Toasted"].ToString();
            txtCheese.Text = dr["Cheese"].ToString();
            txtDrink.Text = dr["DrinkType"].ToString();
            txtCookie.Text = dr["CookieType"].ToString();
            txtCrisp.Text = dr["CrispType"].ToString();
            txtTime.Text = dr["PickupTime"].ToString();
            txtOR.Text = dr["OrderReady"].ToString();
            txtOC.Text = dr["OrderCollected"].ToString();
            txtCode.Text = dr["Codeword"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

I know its a simple flip around of code to navigate backwards, but i can't figure it out!

EDIT:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    String connectionString = staticConnectionString.connectionString;
    OleDbConnection con;
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    OleDbDataReader dr;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Orders;";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A database error has occurred: " +     Environment.NewLine + err.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            btnNext_Click(sender, e);
        }
        btnSave.Enabled = false;

    }
```

Comment: Where do you define `dr` and actually get records from the database?  A `DataReader` is a *forward only* way of reading data from a data source.  If you want to go back to previous records, you will likely need to take a different approach entirely.  (One which doesn't involve keeping an open connection the whole time, ideally.)

Comment: Been defined on the main interface (the interface which is navigating the records). See main post section 'EDIT:'

Comment: @Gavin, while David's advice may be good, it is probably overkill for what you are looking for. You may just want a [BindingNavigator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To @Crowcoder 's point you'll probably also be more comfortable with [DataTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)  which are similar to disconnected ado recordsets. You'll see datasets in the docs which are collecitons of DataTables but in practice usually only have one datatable in them

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are wrong here:

1. `DataReader` is a *forward-only* reader of data.  So it can't "go back a record".
2. Keeping a constant open connection to a database is a famously bad idea.

Given that, you're going to need to re-design your approach a bit.  First, you need to define what the *concepts* of "Next" and "Previous" even mean.  Consider your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
```

In what order does that return records?  Undefined.  Sorting is not guaranteed by the database unless you actually specify a sort order.  Which could be something as simple as this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY Id
```

The point is, you need to define an ordering.  And also understand that *the underlying data can change while the program is running*.

Once you have this, at a high level consider a design which does the following:

1. Opens the form, selects the "first" record (`TOP 1`?  Not sure if Access uses that, you may have to tinker with the syntax.), displays that record in the form controls.
2. When clicking "Next", use the data of the *currently displayed* record to query for the "next" record.  Something like: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Orders WHERE Id > @current_id ORDER BY Id`
3. When clicking "Prev", use the data of the *currently displayed* record to query for the "previous" record.  Perhaps something like: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Orders WHERE Id < @current_id ORDER BY Id DESC`

Each action should connect to the database, get the data it needs, and close the connection all in a very tight scope.

---

Basically, don't think of this application as an open interface directly to a database table.  Instead, think of each discrete action within the application and how that specific action should get the data it needs.